# Sitio para correr códigos R online

Tags: r

Necesito correr un código en algún sitio online en R, pues la maquina donde tengo montada toda mi biblioteca de R, sufrio un accidente y necesito correr el codigo online. Existe algún sitio para hacer esto?

Comment: Probaste rstudio.io ? Es ub servicio comercial en fase prueba y mientras tanto gratuíto. Podría servirte para lo que necesitas

Comment: NO me funciona no hace llamada  al libreria y me dice que no están disponibles

Comment: @AsielCabreraGuerrero, ¿que particularmente no te corre? ¿lo has instalado antes?

Comment: @AsielCabreraGuerrero que versiones necesitas de R, de sistema operativo, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta de Hubert es válida, `https://repl.it/` sin duda es una alternativa para correr el código de forma online, sin embargo, por lo que comentas, necesitarías instalar algún que otro paquete adicional. `Repl.it` a la fecha no tiene soporte para hacer esto de forma estándar, es decir de la forma que normalmente lo harías en `rstudio`. Esto por que no ofrece permisos de escritura sobre la carpeta por defecto dónde se instalan los paquetes en R. Resolver esto, es posible pero un poco complejo:

- En primer lugar hay que instalar los paquetes en una carpeta en la que tengamos permisos de escritura
- Luego deberemos hacer que `library` use esta carpeta para encontrar el paquete instalado
- Adicionalmente, otro problema es que no podremos instalar automáticamente las dependencias, es decir si un paquete `A` requiere un paquete `B`, el `A` lo podremos instalar en una carpeta adecuada, pero el `B` por defecto se instalaría en aquella en la cual no tenemos permisos. La solución en este caso es ir instalando las dependencia una a una.

Por ejemplo, si necesitamos el paquete `vegan`, en primer lugar deberemos instalar este y sus dependencias, por ejemplo en la carpeta `home`:

```
install.packages("permute", lib=".")
install.packages("vegan", lib=".")
```

Luego, sí, podremos hacer la carga de los mismos:

```
library("permute",lib.loc=".")
library("vegan",lib.loc=".")
```

La mejor alternativa a esto, sin duda es lo que ya te la sugirió @mpaladino, es decir: [`https://rstudio.cloud/`](https://rstudio.cloud/),  por ahora es de acceso libre, mediante login seguro con cuenta de google o github. Lo que te ofrece, es un `rstudio` totalmente funcional y online. La instalación de nuevos paquetes es exactamente la misma que harías desde un `rstudio` local, es decir, usando la consola, ejecutas:

```
install.packages("vegan")
library("vegan")
```

Comment: Esta pregunta no seria totalmente basada en opiniones?

Comment: @gbianchi, entiendo que pienses que sí, yo no estoy tan seguro. No se estaría preguntando cual es la mejor herramienta sino, si existe alguna. Es como preguntar con que herramientas puedo compilar código C. Tal vez correspondería cerrarla por que el OP no mostró demasiado trabajo de investigación, eso sería más razonable para mi criterio. Mi respuesta en realidad, fue para complementar la respuesta anterior que no responde del todo a lo que pregunta el OP, de hecho pensé en votar para cerrarla originalmente.

Comment: Pero en cualquier caso. no seria una lista de herramientas? o de sitios web? nombrar uno solo, seria basarla en opiniones.. y ninguna respuesta seria la correcta... :/

Comment: es mas.. ya tenemos una lista de sitios para estas cosas.. aca: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2446/324

Comment: Lo que decís, es que discriminar en un solo ejemplo, sería tomar una opinión? no lo había visto de esa forma, puede ser, no digo que no, pero en todo caso, prefiero votar para cerrala con otro motivo. La lista la conozco pero apunta a las necesidades de SOes en particular, el problema es un requerimiento particular del OP que no se puede resolver solo mediante el enlace. La respuesta original de @Hubert Ronald apunta a eso y es incompleta por que no considera este requerimiento, de ahí mi respuesta. No tengo ningún problema en cerrarla de todas formas.

Comment: Tal vez se pueda mejorar la pregunta a un sitio para correr R que cumpla con estas caracteristicas? aunque igual la respuesta puede ser una lista, e indicarle a OP que existe esa pregunta en meta. porque la info que vos decis (y aca te doy la razon) esta, pero mezclada en comentarios. O sea, como esta ahora ,es cualquier sitio, salvo que uno lea los comentarios por todos lados...

Comment: @gbianchi, reformule en una nueva pregunta, acotando el tema al problema  original de `repl.it`: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/235163/es-posible-usar-paquetes-no-est%C3%A1ndar-en-repl-it.  Saludos.

Comment: Considero que la pregunta en sí misma es interesante para dar luces sobre dónde compilar R en línea para aquellos que se inician con este lenguaje de programación o buscan otras alternativas. Sin embargo, concuerdo con @gbianchi que la naturaleza de la misma está basada en opiniones, quizás la necesidad de mostrar en stackoverflow un código rápido y ejecutable en línea de R, me hizo responder esta pregunta, ya que dicha característica -si no me equivoco- solo está disponible acá para las consultas en HTML, CSS y Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios sitios (aplicaciones web), particularmente me decanto por este:

https://repl.it/

Porque tiene otros lenguajes de programación y permite compartir código rápidamente con otros y ejecutarlo al mismo tiempo.

Cada vez que seleccionas un lenguaje de programación en la parte inferior de la [página de inicio](https://repl.it/) (R en este caso), se abre un ambiente de trabajo con un único enlace para compartir.

No es necesario inscribirse o "loguearse" para usar este servicio. Aquí un ejemplo:

https://repl.it/repls/MundaneAlarmedArchives

Comment: Lamentablemente a la fecha `repl.it` no tiene soporte para instalar nuevos paquetes, que es lo que estaría necesitando el OP. :-(

Comment: En realidad, miento un poco, se puede pero no de una forma estándar.

Comment: En https://rstudio.cloud como importo los datos de mi excel, no me deja tienen ke estar en algun servidor???