# ¿Es posible usar un paquete no estándar en Repl.it?

Tags: r

[`repl.it`](https://repl.it/) es una excelente, útil y por ahora gratis, herramienta para la ejecución de código R de forma on-line. Sin embargo tengo dificultades para poder usar paquetería no estándar de R. De hecho al intentar instalar algo, ocurre lo siguiente:

```
install.packages("vegan")

Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages("vegan") :
  'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable
Error in install.packages("vegan") : unable to install packages
```

En la [documentación](https://repl.it/site/docs/repls/packages), solo se menciona que es posible instalar otras librerías o paquetes en el caso de `Python`, `Javascript` o `Ruby`.

¿Existe alguna forma de poder usar paquetes fuera de la distribución base en esta herramienta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No de manera estándar, es decir mediante un simple: `install.packages("vegan")`. El error es claro. No tenemos permiso de escritura en la carpeta dónde iría a parar el nuevo paquete.

Resolver esto, es posible pero un poco complejo, veamos:

- En primer lugar hay que instalar los paquetes en una carpeta en la que tengamos permisos de escritura
- Luego deberemos hacer que `library` use esta carpeta para encontrar el paquete instalado
- Adicionalmente, otro problema es, que no podremos instalar automáticamente las dependencias, es decir si un paquete `A` requiere un paquete `B`, el `A` lo podremos instalar en una carpeta adecuada, pero el `B` por defecto se instalaría en aquella en la cual no tenemos permisos. La solución en este caso es ir instalando las dependencia una a una.

Por ejemplo, si necesitamos el paquete `vegan`, en primer lugar deberemos instalar sus dependencias, en este caso el paquete `permute`. Podemos usar la carpeta `home` del usuario, dónde tenemos los permisos adecuados para hacer esto:

```
install.packages("permute", lib = ".")
install.packages("vegan", lib = ".")
```

Luego, sí, podremos hacer la carga de los mismos, pero deberemos indicar la localización de estas librerías:

```
library("permute", lib.loc = ".")
library("vegan", lib.loc = ".")
```

#### Observación secundaria

Agrego, que otra alternativa podría ser: [`https://rstudio.cloud`](https://rstudio.cloud/), por ahora es de acceso libre, mediante login seguro con cuenta de `google` o `github`. Lo que te ofrece, es un `rstudio` totalmente funcional y online. La instalación y uso de nuevos paquetes es exactamente la misma que harías desde un `rstudio` local.

Comment: Bien detallado @PatricioMoracho, quería agregar que existe una solución -claro no oficial de repl.it- para instalar los paquetes de R sin hacer referencia a sus dependencias, aunque igual requiere cuidado.

Esto se logra creando un archivo `requirements.txt` en home y dentro de el, van los enlaces de CRAN de aquellos paquetes que deseamos instalar.

¿Por qué funciona lo anterior? por el [pip (package manager)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(package_manager)), ya que se está ejecutando dentro de repl.it el comando `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Para el caso que expusiste dejo el respectivo enlace [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/ParchedDecisiveMoto) si logras ver las carpetas de  `permute` y `vegan` significa que alguien ya ejecutó el código, pero igual se pueden borrar y ejecutar el código de nuevo.

La consideración sería el orden entre los enlaces guardados en el archivo `requirements.txt` (enlaces a paquetes: b, a, c uno por cada línea del archivo) y los que se ponen en la consola `install.packages("b", lib = "."); ...` al invocar las bibliotecas es importante tomar tus palabras: el orden de las dependencias es relevante.

Comment: No obstante las acotaciones anteriores, al instalar paquetes más grandes o con más dependencias como `devtools` o `ggplot2`, la plataforma va lenta -la solución como dije no es oficial-, también al ejecutar el código una vez se ha instalado los paquetes hay que colocarles `#` para que al ejecutar el código -con todas sus bibliotecas- obvie este paso.

Comment: @HubertRonald, conocía el uso de requirements.txt pero para python, desconocía que se podía usar para un proyecto R. Buen dato!